# The Page_Load calls the function, but nothing happens

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

as the title suggests I have this problem: the function is called, but it does not generate anything for me.

in the function in question I created a `DataTable` with `DataRows`, which are subsequently populated. In `Page_Load` I call the function, but when I launch the debug on the web page nothing appears. The error is probably in the function, because doing a debug I notice that it is called

```
public partial class ElencoProvince : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    
   


    public void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    
    {
         GetTable();

    }

     public static DataTable GetTable()
    
     {
        DataTable table = new DataTable();

        table.Columns.Add("Nome", typeof(string));
        table.Columns.Add("Cognome", typeof(string));
        table.Columns.Add("Azienda", typeof(string));
        table.Columns.Add("Provincia", typeof(string));

        DataRow row = table.NewRow();
        row["Nome"] = "Mario";
        row["Cognome"] = "Rossi";
        row["Azienda"] = "Pippo";
        row["Provincia"] = "Viterbo";
        table.Rows.Add(row);

        return table;
    }
   
}
```

Could anyone tell me where I'm wrong?

Comment: You're returning a value to a function that returns void.  Either your GetTable() needs to update a web element or the Page_Load() needs to do something with the return value from GetTable()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To see your table you need to add  it to a GridView

```
 public void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    
    {
       
      GridView gv = new GridView();
      gv.ID = "gv" ;
      gv.DataSource =   GetTable();
      gv.DataBind();
           
       this.Controls.Add(gv);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Page_Load is a void function and does not return anything.
To view the data you need to bind it to some control on the screen.

You should ideally also check for if it is postback.

[Microsoft Docs on Gridview Databind](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.databind?view=netframework-4.8)